# A Question about Answer Keys

Tags: teaching

I am a HS math teacher and just started a job that adopted a new curriculum at the last minute. It gave us the tasks but did not provide any answer keys. Of course, I know how to work through the math but I would prefer not to spend the 1-2 hours every single week creating the answer keys for my 3 separate courses.

The tasks are freely, publicly available online to anyone so it not proprietary stuff that I shouldn't be sharing. I have heard about sites like Nerdify where freelancers can assist. Does anyone have an opinion on them or have any other advice for what I am trying to do?

And yes I know plenty of math educators who will hate every word of my question here and would tell me to work through every single example myself :). I have a busy year and was hoping to find a solution to save me time even if it costs me some $. Thank you for reading

Comment: Why do you feel compelled to provide answer keys?

Comment: You can also try some math. major at a local university, if you have one nearby (graduate students are especially well-suited for the task and, as far as I can tell, are always looking for some extra money-making options).

Comment: The publisher of the curriculum won't provide answer keys? They usually have teacher's guides with all sorts of suggestions, including answers.

Comment: "The tasks are freely, publicly available online to anyone so it not proprietary stuff that I shouldn't be sharing." -- I recommend sharing the name of the curriculum and/or a link to it. Perhaps someone here knows of an existing solution set, etc.

Comment: So you want to grade tasks that you hand out using answer keys instead of doing them yourself? Oof.

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain what is an "HS" and what is an "answer key"?

Comment: @Stef: HS -- [high school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_school); [answer key](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answer_key)

Comment: Are you the only teacher in your school teaching your three courses?  If not, then you can ask them for their answer keys.

Comment: WolframAlpha pro will generate answers showing steps for any equation, simplifying expression, algebra, trig. exercise, etc., but not yet for word problems or geometric figures.

Comment: If you're grading then it's just faster to create your own key and grade. The time it takes to understand someone else's key to competently grade is comparable to the time to make the key. Not to mention, you rob yourself of the only fun part of grading.

Comment: "The tasks are freely, publicly available online to anyone" If this is Free stuff and you do work up an answer key, please consider contributing it.

Answer (score 6):

Don't underestimate the value of working through the problems yourself. When I assign problems to students, I am not just checking to see if they got the answer correct or not -- I am looking for patterns, common mistakes, thought processes, etc. If you create your own answer key, you can write up your answers from the perspective of your students, showing the steps. I do the same with my middle schoolers, and it helps me anticipate what kinds of mistakes they might make. Hope this helps!